# WP Admin: Filter for a Custom Taxonomy and see posts of any/all status?

Tags: wordpress

On Admin > Edit Posts (edit.php), how can I filter for a Custom Taxonomy and see posts of ANY status, not just Published?

For example, say I have a Custom Taxonomy "Color"...

These queries find posts of ANY status:

- edit.php?category_name=foo
- edit.php?author=3
- edit.php?tag=foo

And this query works correctly:

- edit.php?color=red&post_status=draft

But this query finds ONLY Published posts:

- edit.php?color=red

Answer (score 0):

Drop this in a plugin or your theme's `functions.php`;

```
if (is_admin()):

function my_query_parser(&$query)
{
    if (!isset($_GET['post_status']))
        $query->query_vars['post_status'] = 'any';
}
add_action('parse_query', 'my_query_parser');

endif;
```

Personally I would class this as a bug in WP, I'll post it up in trac.

UPDATE:

It seems [this trac entry](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12750) mentions the issue, and it's reportedly fixed (probably in the nightly build).